# AvalonEdit Folding Strategy for VB

Tags: c#, avalonedit

I am developing a C# application which supports scripting. Does any have a sample `FoldingStrategy` for Visual Basic code to be used for code folding for AvalonEdit?

Comment: There is one supplied with the source code in C#. This is a bracket matching strategy that should be easily extended.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I created which appears to work... rather well.
Not perfect, as it doesn't take into consideration many possible situations but it's a start.

```
Imports ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Folding
Imports ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document

Public Class VBNETFoldingStrategy
    Inherits AbstractFoldingStrategy

    Private foldableKeywords() As String = {"namespace", "class", "sub", "function", "structure", "enum"}

    Public Overrides Function CreateNewFoldings(document As ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document.TextDocument, ByRef firstErrorOffset As Integer) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Folding.NewFolding)
        firstErrorOffset = -1

        Dim foldings As New List(Of NewFolding)

        Dim text As String = document.Text
        Dim lowerCaseText As String = text.ToLower()

        For Each foldableKeyword In foldableKeywords
            foldings.AddRange(GetFoldings(text, lowerCaseText, foldableKeyword))
        Next

        Return foldings.OrderBy(Function(f) f.StartOffset)
    End Function

    Public Function GetFoldings(text As String, lowerCaseText As String, keyword As String) As IEnumerable(Of NewFolding)
        Dim foldings As New List(Of NewFolding)

        Dim closingKeyword As String = "end " + keyword
        Dim closingKeywordLength As String = closingKeyword.Length

        keyword += " "
        Dim keywordLength As String = keyword.Length

        Dim startOffsets As New Stack(Of Integer)

        For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - closingKeywordLength
            If lowerCaseText.Substring(i, keywordLength) = keyword Then
                Dim k As Integer = i
                If k <> 0 Then
                    Dim lastLetterPos As Integer = i
                    Do Until text(k - 1) = vbLf OrElse text(k - 1) = vbCr
                        If Char.IsLetter(text(k)) Then lastLetterPos = k
                        k -= 1
                    Loop
                    If lastLetterPos > k Then k = lastLetterPos
                End If
                startOffsets.Push(k)
            ElseIf lowerCaseText.Substring(i, closingKeywordLength) = closingKeyword Then
                Dim startOffset As Integer = startOffsets.Pop()
                Dim newFolding As NewFolding = New NewFolding(startOffset, i + closingKeywordLength)
                Dim p As Integer = text.IndexOf(vbLf, startOffset)
                If p = -1 Then p = text.IndexOf(vbCr, startOffset)
                If p = -1 Then p = text.Length - 1
                newFolding.Name = text.Substring(startOffset, p - startOffset)
                foldings.Add(newFolding)
            End If
        Next

        Return foldings
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

i found two errors on this code. there are two out of range exeptions at:

```
Do Until text(k - 1) = vbLf OrElse text(k - 1) = vbCr
```

if k runns to 0. i fixed that by one line:

```
k -= 1
If k <= 0 Then Exit Do
```

and at:

```
Dim startOffset As Integer = startOffsets.Pop()
```

if startOffset is empty this one if fixed by:

```
If startOffsets.Count > 0 Then
    Dim startOffset As Integer = startOffsets.Pop()
    .....
End If
```

But the Folding generation Fails on InlineSubs. Try this Example:

```
Public Class Window
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler TextBox.TextChanged, Sub(TBsender As Object, TBe As EventArgs)
                                             CheckCode()
                                        End Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

I didn't manage to fix this last problem.